# eclipse on Windows with gcc through msys2: CMake4eclipse plugin throw an error

Tags: windows, eclipse, gcc, cmake, msys2

I configured eclipse with gcc/msys2 according with the following steps: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/how-setup-gcc-msys2-eclipse-windows-c-development

gcc and eclipse work fine togehter in CDT Managed build, but when I use the cmake4eclipse plugin, I become the following error:

"C:\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe" -C "bin\bin -j3" all
make: *** bin\bin -j3: No such file or directory.  Stop.
"C:/msys64/usr/bin/make.exe -C bin\bin -j3 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Here are the involved files:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)

set(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME "test")
project($(CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME))

add_executable(tst tst2.cpp)
```

tst2.cpp
#include 
using namespace std;

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Hello Jose";
    return 0;
}
```

Had anybody the same issue? Somebody so kind to help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The command seems to be wrong: `"bin\bin -j3"` -> `"bin\bin" -j3`. I don't know if it's your fault on a broken plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Sometimes it uses only bin, but throw the same error. There is no problem on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution came after installing the mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake 3.23.0-1 cmake package. Just msys/cmake 3.22.1-2 was not enough

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, cmake4eclipse has the concept of *Build Toolkit* to set the PATH environment variable. This has been introduced to make it easier to build on windows. Just search the online help of eclipse for details.

BTW: I am the maintainer of cmake4eclipse.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to PATH? Make seems to receive an invalid directory path.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Your're right: -C "bin\bin -j3" No idea, why.

Comment: Thank you. I googled but I could not find anything about the build toolkit on the last year :-(. I'm sorry. An assumption: Could be that the plugin send a relative path to compiler when it needs an absolute??